# ionic 2 headers not being set before the http request

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic2

I have the following request to my backend:

```
loggedIn() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.getToken().then((val) => {
        headers.append('X-Auth-Token', val);
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let seq = this.api.post('/login', null, options).share();
    seq.map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {

        }, err => {
            console.log("HEADERS ------- ", options.headers);
        });
    return seq;
};
```

Sometimes 'X-Auth-Token' isn't being set. How's it possible to make sure that the header is being set?

getToken() looks like this:

```
getToken() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
        return value;
    });
}
```

The method that calls loggedIn() looks like this:

```
checkIfLoggedIn() {
    this.user.loggedIn()
        .subscribe((res) => {
            console.log("LoginPage RETURN VALUE --------------- ", res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("LoginPage RETURN ERROR --------------- ", err);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to ensure the api post after header had data

```
loggedIn() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.getToken().then((val) => {
        headers.append('X-Auth-Token', val);
         const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
         let seq = this.api.post('/login', null, options).share();
         seq.map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {

            }, err => {
                console.log("HEADERS ------- ", options.headers);
            });
        return seq;
    });

};
```

Comment: I tried it but then I can't .subscribe() to loggedIn() from the method checkIfLoggedIn()

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem but i am using ionic 3. this is actually happens because of async manner of js code. i found answer from other stackoverflow question which will help you out to solve this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298747/2036977